# What are temporal and local data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-mining

Based on the question, what are they and what are their differences? I've seen a lot those terms but cannot find an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Temporal data is across time. Data points are correlated and you model them using a variant of RNNs (LSTMs, GRUs, Tree recursive NNs etc). example would be text script of speech. Notice how each data point would be correlated with the previous data point

local data is ambiguous and could mean a lot of things. local to a particular location? local data as opposed to server data? local to a particular task? etc etc. Please provide context